# Pressurized Container Automation

Tags: water-pressure

Not quite home-improvement, however the engineering question lends itself to the expertise of the fine folks in this forum.

I am interested in pressurizing a hopper of tennis balls with a device like:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03Ml7_A78yo

I would like the device to be limited to 12 PSI, so I am thinking a pressure relief valve for safety and that for simplicity, an electric pump to bring the pressure to 12 PSI and shut off automagically at the target presure.

Is there a **simple and inexpensive** control mechanism that can cut off the electric pump when it reaches the target pressure.  Ideally one could 'dial in' the target pressure.

The goal is for the non-technical tennis player is able to quickly / easily / SAFELY pressurize and depressurize the container.

Comment: So not home improvement, but product recommendation/shopping for pressure switches?

Answer (score 3):

There are potential safety concerns using a pressurized vessel for use outside of its design parameters. An air pig can easily be purchased with known ratings and pressure relief built in. Couple an air Pig with a pressure regulator and you'll have yourself a portable pressurized vessel that is safe and dialable. **This is an example of an air pig**[image]www.homedepot.com

**A regulator**
[image]https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjr1pjM-4HhAhUMGWkKHb2FARAYABABGgJpcQ&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAESEeD20JjDAVGqz-qgNA4TwoqW&sig=AOD64_2SRn-l4VT0e71n6VYTSpO7n5oFqQ&ctype=46&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjRpZPM-4HhAhXo1IMKHYNtBjIQzzl6BAgLEAc&adurl=

You won't get much use out of it in between charges due to the volume of the pressure vessel. To get a usable amount of air in the tank you may need to recharge frequently in order to do that you may want to get a portable air pump.

**Battery operated air pump**[image]https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwi7mov9_IHhAhWXtcAKHd3XCHkYABATGgJpbQ&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAESEeD2amOzOw3QuE2L556cw1ed&sig=AOD64_2n1jgSPZIA_daVlU_5O156gmhCYA&ctype=46&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjp-IP9_IHhAhWO_YMKHVMCBokQzzl6BAgLEAc&adurl=

Milwaukee also makes an digitally set battery operated air pump but I don't know the range. My friend has it. But I don't know if it goes down to 12psi.

***Edit***

It does, here's a link. It's available in m12 or m18

**milwaukee m12 pump**[image]https://toolguyd.com/milwaukee-m12-cordless-inflator-review

Comment: I've never heard the term Air Pig before, but that's perfect.  Now I really want one painted like a pig.  Also, ugly links can be wrapped using the [inline link syntax](https://diy.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) to make them more palatable.

Comment: I do this on my phone but I'm going to try to figure it out. Thanks for the link to the link. Lol

Answer (score 0):

Use an adjustable pressure switch to turn the pump on / off.

[Something like this](https://m.distrelec.ch/en/digital-pressure-switch-mpa-g1-internal-thread-smc-ise70-f02-65/p/15454326?channel=b2c&price_gs=175.8741&wt_mc=ch.cse.gshop.en.-&source=googleps&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3O-Fo-mA4QIVSbvtCh1pSg_fEAQYAiABEgLuIPD_BwE) may be suitable, but there are many others...

Comment: You know you can use [inline links](https://diy.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) to hide ugly URLs like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are looking for a pressure regulator. You can buy at local store or online.

Comment: Will a pressure regulator turn off the pump or just dump excess pressure?